# Using templates to wrap variardic JNI method calls into type-safe C++ functors

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, variadic, jni

I am working on a project which uses JNI. More than once I fell over the absence of type safety working with the variardic function calls. So I came up with this module. It wraps the variardic JNI functions using C++ variardc templates to offer a type-safe alternative. It also features integrated error checking for more compact code. This could be of use to others. I want to flesh it out and then publish it so others may base their work on it. This is the first time I really used templates in C++. I know it works well for me, but I also want to know whether the design is good. I am grateful for your opinions.

In the code below, I omitted the repetitive implementations which only differ in the type used. You can find the complete code [here](https://github.com/hoehermann/TypedJNI).

#### Use-Case

Instead of the lengthy and error-prone

```
jclass jcls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "SomeClass");
if (jcls == NULL) {
    return; // handle error
}
jmethodID constructor = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, jcls, "<init>", "(JLjava/lang/String;)V");
if (constructor == NULL) {
    return; // handle error
}
jstring jsomestring = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, somestring);
if (jsomestring == NULL) {
    return; // handle error
}
jlong jsomelong = somelong; // explicitly convert
jobject jobj = (*env)->NewObject(env, jcls, constructor, jsomelong, jsomestring);
if (jobj == NULL) {
    return; // handle error
}
jmethodID method = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, jcls, "someMethod", "()V");
if (method == NULL) {
    return; // handle error
}
(*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, jobj, method);
(*env)->DeleteLocalRef(jsomestring); // late cleanup
(*env)->DeleteLocalRef(jobj);
```

you can now write

```
try {
    tenv.find_class("SomeClass").
        GetConstructor<jlong,jstring>()(
            some_number, // implicit conversion where possible
            tenv.make_jstring(some_string) // explicit conversion with automated clean-up
        ).
        GetMethod<void()>("someMethod")();
} catch (std::exception & e) {
    // handle error
}
```

.

#### Header

```
#pragma once

#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

/**
 * Exception class for all runtime errors regarding TypedJNI.
 */
class TypedJNIError : public std::runtime_error 
{
    public:
    TypedJNIError(const std::string& what_arg);
};

namespace TypedJNI { // namespace for internal helper functions
/**
 * GetTypeString maps the type arguments to the corresponding JNI type signature.
 * 
 * * GetTypeString<jboolean>() → "Z"
 * * GetTypeString<jbyte>() → "B"
 * * and so on
 * 
 * The full list is at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html#type_signatures.
 * 
 * Can handle an arbitrary number of arguments: `GetTypeString<jboolean,jbyte>()` → "ZB"
 */
template <typename T>
std::string GetTypeString(){
    // this declares the templated function, but the default template may never actually be used
    static_assert(std::is_same<T,void>::value, "Cannot handle this type.");
    return "This actually never gets compiled.";
};
template <> std::string GetTypeString<void>();
template <> std::string GetTypeString<jboolean>();
template <> std::string GetTypeString<jint>();
template <> std::string GetTypeString<jlong>();
template <> std::string GetTypeString<jstring>();
template<typename T, typename... Args>
typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Args) != 0, std::string>::type
GetTypeString() {
    // recursively expand type string
    return GetTypeString<T>() + GetTypeString<Args...>();
};
template<typename... Args>
typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Args) == 0, std::string>::type
GetTypeString() {
    // end of recursion
    return "";
};

/**
 * Wrapper around GetStaticMethodID(…)
 * 
 * Performs error-checking. Throws an exception on error.
 */
jmethodID GetStaticMethodID(JNIEnv *env, const jclass cls, const std::string name, const std::string & signature);

/**
 * Wrapper around GetMethodID(…)
 * 
 * Performs error-checking. Throws an exception on error.
 */
jmethodID GetMethodID(JNIEnv *env, const jclass cls, const std::string name, const std::string & signature);
} // namespace TypedJNI

/**
 * TypedJNIStaticMethod selects the corresponding JNI function for static methods based on the requested return type.
 * 
 * * TypedJNIStaticMethod<void>::get(…) → CallStaticVoidMethod
 * * TypedJNIStaticMethod<jint>::get(…) → CallStaticIntMethod
 * * and so on
 * 
 * The full list is at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#calling_static_methods.
 * 
 * For convenience, jstring is handled explicitly. All other objects are jobject. 
 * 
 * Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065081/.
 */
template<typename T> 
class TypedJNIStaticMethod;
template<typename ...Args> 
class TypedJNIStaticMethod<void(Args...)>
{
    public:
    static std::function<void(Args...)> get(JNIEnv *env, const jclass cls, const std::string & name) {
        jmethodID mid = TypedJNI::GetStaticMethodID(env, cls, name, "("+TypedJNI::GetTypeString<Args...>()+")"+TypedJNI::GetTypeString<void>());
        return [env, cls, mid](Args... args) {
            env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, mid, args...);
        };
    }
};
// other types omitted for less code to review

/**
 * Like TypedJNIStaticMethod, but for object methods.
 */
template<typename T> 
class TypedJNIMethod;
template<typename ...Args> 
class TypedJNIMethod<void(Args...)>
{
    public:
    static std::function<void(Args...)> get(JNIEnv *env, const jclass cls, const jobject obj, const std::string & name) {
        jmethodID mid = TypedJNI::GetMethodID(env, cls, name, "("+TypedJNI::GetTypeString<Args...>()+")"+TypedJNI::GetTypeString<void>());
        return [env, obj, mid](Args... args) {
            env->CallVoidMethod(obj, mid, args...);
        };
    }
};
// other types omitted for less code to review

/**
 * Class for a proxy object referencing a Java object.
 * 
 * The local reference to the Java object is deleted when the last copy of the proxy object is destroyed.
 */
class TypedJNIObject {
    private:
    JNIEnv *env = nullptr;
    jclass cls = nullptr;
    std::shared_ptr<_jobject> obj = nullptr;
    public:
    TypedJNIObject(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jobject obj);
    template<typename... Args>
    std::function<Args...> GetMethod(const std::string name) {
        return TypedJNIMethod<Args...>::get(env, cls, obj.get(), name);
    }
};

/**
 * Special case of TypedJNIMethod for accessing a Java constructor.
 */
template<typename ...Args> 
class TypedJNIConstructor
{
    public:
    static std::function<TypedJNIObject(Args...)> get(JNIEnv *env, const jclass cls) {
        // yes indeed GetMethodID as illustrated at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260376/ (not get GetStaticMethodID)
        const jmethodID mid = TypedJNI::GetMethodID(env, cls, "<init>", "("+TypedJNI::GetTypeString<Args...>()+")"+TypedJNI::GetTypeString<void>());
        return [env, cls, mid](Args... args) -> TypedJNIObject {
            return TypedJNIObject(env, cls, env->NewObject(cls, mid, args...));
        };
    }
};

/**
 * Special case of TypedJNIObject for convenient string conversion.
 * 
 * Uses NewStringUTF (expects Java modified Unicode, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7921016).
 */
class TypedJNIString {
    private:
    std::shared_ptr<_jstring> jstrptr = nullptr;
    public:
    TypedJNIString(JNIEnv *env, const std::string & str);
    operator jstring() const;
};

/**
 * Class for a proxy object referencing a Java class.
 * 
 * Static methods can be accessed as well as the constructors.
 */
class TypedJNIClass {
    private:
    JNIEnv *env = nullptr;
    public:
    const jclass cls = nullptr;
    TypedJNIClass(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls);
    template<typename... Args>
    std::function<Args...> GetStaticMethod(const std::string name) {
        return TypedJNIStaticMethod<Args...>::get(env, cls, name);
    }
    template<typename... Args>
    std::function<TypedJNIObject(Args...)> GetConstructor() {
        return TypedJNIConstructor<Args...>::get(env, cls);
    }
};

/**
 * Class for creating a Java VM and Environment.
 * 
 * Wrapper around JNI_CreateJavaVM.
 * 
 * Performs error-checking. Throws an exception on error.
 * 
 * Provides access to Java classes and utility methods.
 * 
 * The VM is destroyed with the TypedJNIEnv object.
 */
class TypedJNIEnv {
    private:
    JavaVM *vm = nullptr;
    public:
    /**
     * The environment is provided by a naked pointer.
     * 
     * This is public so functionality not wrapped by TypedJNI can use direct access.
     */
    JNIEnv *env = nullptr;
    TypedJNIEnv(const TypedJNIEnv&) = delete;
    TypedJNIEnv& operator=(const TypedJNIEnv&) = delete;
    TypedJNIEnv(JavaVMInitArgs vm_args);
    virtual ~TypedJNIEnv();
    
    /**
     * Find a Java class from the Java runtime.
     */
    TypedJNIClass find_class(std::string name);
    
    /**
     * Create a Java String from a std::string.
     */
    TypedJNIString make_jstring(const std::string & str);
};
```

#### Implementation

```
#include "typedjni.hpp"

TypedJNIError::TypedJNIError(const std::string& what_arg) : std::runtime_error(what_arg) {};

template <> std::string TypedJNI::GetTypeString<void>(){return "V";};
template <> std::string TypedJNI::GetTypeString<jboolean>(){return "Z";};
template <> std::string TypedJNI::GetTypeString<jint>(){return "I";};
template <> std::string TypedJNI::GetTypeString<jlong>(){return "J";};
template <> std::string TypedJNI::GetTypeString<jstring>(){return "Ljava/lang/String;";};

jmethodID TypedJNI::GetStaticMethodID(JNIEnv *env, const jclass cls, const std::string name, const std::string & signature) {
    jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, name.c_str(), signature.c_str());
    if (mid == NULL) {
        throw TypedJNIError("Failed to find static method '"+name+"' "+signature+".");
    }
    return mid;
}

jmethodID TypedJNI::GetMethodID(JNIEnv *env, const jclass cls, const std::string name, const std::string & signature) {
    jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(cls, name.c_str(), signature.c_str());
    if (mid == NULL) {
        throw TypedJNIError("Failed to find method '"+name+"' "+signature+".");
    }
    return mid;
}

TypedJNIObject::TypedJNIObject(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jobject obj) : 
    env(env), 
    cls(cls),
    obj(std::shared_ptr<_jobject>(obj, [env](jobject o){env->DeleteLocalRef(o);})) {};

TypedJNIString::TypedJNIString(JNIEnv *env, const std::string & str) {
    jstring jstr = env->NewStringUTF(str.c_str());
    if (jstr == NULL) {
        throw TypedJNIError("NewStringUTF failed for string '"+str+"'.");
    }
    jstrptr = std::shared_ptr<_jstring>(jstr, [env](jstring s){env->DeleteLocalRef(s);});
}

TypedJNIString::operator jstring() const {
    return jstrptr.get();
}

TypedJNIClass::TypedJNIClass(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls) : env(env), cls(cls) {
    if (!cls) {
        throw TypedJNIError("Tried to create TypedJNIClass from nullptr.");
    }
};

TypedJNIEnv::TypedJNIEnv(JavaVMInitArgs vm_args) {
    jint res = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&vm, (void **)&env, &vm_args);
    if (res != JNI_OK) {
        throw TypedJNIError(std::string("Failed to create Java VM (error ")+std::to_string(res)+").");
    }
}

TypedJNIEnv::~TypedJNIEnv() {
    vm->DestroyJavaVM();
}

TypedJNIClass TypedJNIEnv::find_class(std::string name) {
    jclass cls = env->FindClass(name.c_str());
    if (cls == NULL) {
        throw TypedJNIError("Failed to find class '"+name+"'.");
    }
    return TypedJNIClass(env, cls);
}

TypedJNIString TypedJNIEnv::make_jstring(const std::string & str) {
    return TypedJNIString(env, str);
}
```

Comment: For further reference: I found a flaw in the design regarding the deleter in `TypedJNIObject`. If the last C++ instance goes out of scope, the deleter is called and the Java object is garbage collected. To compensate, `TypedJNIMethod::get` now captures the `TypedJNIObject` instance rather than the raw and potentially dangling pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Consider changing the interface

I'm not very familiar with Java, but I assume you want the interface to the Java classes to feel as native C++ as possible. Your example code does not really look like native C++:

```
    tenv.find_class("SomeClass").
        GetConstructor<jlong,jstring>()(
            some_number, // implicit conversion where possible
            tenv.make_jstring(some_string) // explicit conversion with automated clean-up
        ).
        GetMethod<void()>("someMethod")();
```

Part of it is the function names: I would expect `GetConstructor()` to return a constructor, but not actually construct the object. Perhaps it should just be renamed `Construct()`, but that still doesn't feel right; you never have to write `std::string foo = std::string::GetConstructor()("Hello")` in C++.

Let's start with how I would want the interface to work:

```
auto psclass = tenv.find_class("SomeClass");
auto object = psclass(some_number, tenv.make_jstring(some_string));
object.call<void()>("someMethod")();
```

In the above example, creating a class object would work the same as you already have. But then to construct it, I want to feel it as much C++ as possible. Overloading `operator()` of `TypedJNIClass` would allow you to do that to a certain extent (you can write `std::string = std::string("Hello")` after all). Also, I wouldn't want to have to specify the template parameters, so let the compiler deduce them automatically. Here's a possible implementation:

```
class TypedJNIClass {
    ...
    template<typename... Args>
    TypedJNIObject operator()(Args... &&args) {
        const jmethodID mid = TypedJNI::GetMethodID(env, cls, "<init>", "(" + TypedJNI::GetTypeString<Args...>() + ")" + TypedJNI::GetTypeString<void>());
        return TypedJNIObject(env, cls, env->NewObject(cls, mid, args...));
    }
};
```

And then for calling methods, I would want to avoid the two-step process, and not first get a lambda and then pass the parameters to the lambda:

```
class TypedJNIObject {
    ...
    template<typename... Args>
    auto call(const std::string &name, Args... &&args) {
        return TypedJNIMethod<Args...>::get(env, cls, obj.get(), name)(args);
    }
};
```

Of course, the latter might be inefficient if you repeatedly want to call the same method.

## What about functions that return something?

You only handle functions that return `void`. I'm sure someone would want to use this to get some data back from the Java methods they are calling.

## Enforce copy semantics for objects

C++ programmers are used to copy semantics. However, it looks like you wrote `TypedJNIObject` in such a way that if you write:

```
auto object1 = tenv.find_class("SomeClass")(...);
auto object2 = object1;
```

Then both `object1` and `object2` refer to the same Java object. This could be very confusing. I recommend that you change the type of `TypedJNIObject::obj` from `std::shared_ptr` to `std::unique_ptr`, and write a copy constructor for it that actually creates a deep copy of the object, so it behaves like a regular C++ object. If a C++ programmer wants to avoid a deep copy, they'd just use references explicitly:

```
auto object1 = tenv.find_class("SomeClass")(...);
auto &object2 = object1;
```

## Avoid repeating the name of a `namespace` in its members

Many things inside `namespace TypedJNI` are prefixed with `TypedJNI`, but that is unnecessary duplication. You can remove that prefix from all its member functions and classes. Code using your classes can just write:

```
TypedJNI::Class psclass = tenv.find_class("SomeClass");
```

Comment: Thank you for your review. I was sure about many of the points you mentioned. I just updated the interface according to your suggestion. I definitely want to look if I can make the automatic template parameter deduction work. Many (but not all) other return types are actually implemented – I just left them out of the review because it is all the same (except for the type, of course). I was unsure whether a prefix or a namespace would be better (you can tell from the code I was undecided). Your answer made me lean more towards namespaces.

Comment: The C++ copy semantics are another good point. I am doubtful I can implement that as Java objects – as far as I know – are not guaranteed to provide a mechanism for creating a deep copy. Users will need to keep it in mind. But I want to add it to the comment for clarification.